# Cross product of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, function, cross-product

As a part of a program that I'm writing, I need to find the cross product of a vector of doubles and a vector of complex doubles. I've written a function that I feel should do this, but when I call it, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘CrossProduct1D(std::vector< double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >&)’
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

//1D cross product
template <typename T>
vector<T> CrossProduct1D(vector<T> const &a, vector<T> const &b)
{
  vector<T> r (a.size());  
  r[0] = a[1]*b[2]-a[2]*b[1];
  r[1] = a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2];
  r[2] = a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0];
  return r;
}

//::::::::importing data from text::::::::::
  vector<string> ezivec;
  ezivec.reserve(4000);

  string ezidat("ez.i.txt");

  ifstream ezifile;
  ezifile.open(ezidat.c_str());

  if(!ezifile.is_open())
    {
      cerr<<"Error opening file : "<<ezidat.c_str()<<endl;
      return -1;
    }

  string ezistr; //store lines in vector
  while(getline(ezifile, ezistr, ';'))
    {
      ezivec.push_back(ezistr);
    }

  ezifile.close();

 //Converting from vector of strings to vector of floats
  vector<double> ezi (ezivec.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < ezivec.size(); ++i)
    {
      ezi[i] = string_to_T<double>(ezivec[i]);
    }

 //

  vector<string> ezrvec;
  ezrvec.reserve(4000); 

  string ezrdat("ez.r.txt");

  ifstream ezrfile;
  ezrfile.open(ezrdat.c_str());

  if(!ezrfile.is_open())
    {
      cerr<<"Error opening file : "<<ezrdat.c_str()<<endl;
      return -1;
    }

  string ezrstr;
  while(getline(ezrfile, ezrstr, ';'))
    {
      ezrvec.push_back(ezrstr);
    }

  ezrfile.close();

  vector<double> ezr (ezrvec.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < ezrvec.size(); ++i)
    {
      ezr[i] = string_to_T<double>(ezrvec[i]);
    }

//:::::::defining vectors:::::::
vector<vector<complex<double> > > E0 (ezi.size(), vector<complex<double> > (3));
for(int i = 0; i < ezi.size(); i++)
{
  E0[i][0].real() = 0.0;
  E0[i][0].imag() = 0.0;
  E0[i][1].real() = 0.0;
  E0[i][1].imag() = 0.0;;
  E0[i][2].real() = ezr[i];
  E0[i][2].imag() = ezi[i];
} 

vector<double> n_a (3);
n_a[0] = 1.0;
n_a[1] = 0.0;
n_a[2] = 0.0;

//:::::::calling cross product:::::::
for(int j = 1; j < jmax; j++)
    {
      M[j] = CrossProduct1D(n_a, E0[j]);
    }
```

"ez.i.txt" and "ez.r.txt" are semicolon-delimited text files of 4000 numbers.

Comment: When asking about a compiler error you should directly quote the compiler's entire message. Your code isn't complete nor simple, so someone will have to put nontrivial effort to reproduce your problem. You're less likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: As far as I know, the cross product operator is only defined for R^4

Comment: @Adam Sorry, I've edited my post.

Comment: The code still isn't complete. Try compiling it, and it'll give you dozens of errors complaining that there's no definitions for string_to_T, M, jmax, etc., not to mention that you've got a whole bunch of code sitting at namespace level instead of inside a function.

Answer (score 10):

Your template function is parameterized on a single type, `T`, and takes two `vector<T>` but you are trying to pass it two different types of vectors so there is no single `T` that can be selected.

You could have two template parameters, e.g.

```
template<class T, class U> CrossProduct1D(std::vector<T> const& a,
                                          std::vector<U> const& b)
```