# How to get plane-vertices by a point and normal

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, glm-math

I'm having a point `p` and a normal `n` (in 3d space).
I want to calculate 4 vertex-points which are lying on the plane which is perpendicular to the normal and lies on the point `p`.

The vertices should form a rectangle and `p` should be the center of this rectangle.

[image]

Comment: This is a maths question and other sites would be a better bet to get the answer for your homework.

Comment: You could calculate a perpendicular vector to the normal and successively rotate that through 90 degrees to find your points. The matrices to perform those operations should be findable through google.

Comment: @Ed Heal: this is not a homework related question. Its a question regarding a game problem.

Comment: @Galik: How can I calculate a perpendicular vector with only one given vector?

Comment: You could use a transformation matrix to rotate your vector through 90°. It would end up pointing in an arbitrary direction in the plane. Then you could take a cross product from your original vector and rotated vector to get another vector that is perpendicular to the first two. Then you should have 3 points in your plane, and you can go from there for the other 2 vertices.

Comment: @Logicrat: sounds good. How do I form a transformation matrix around my vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very useful tool is the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) (from high school analytic geometry). This takes as an input an ordered pair of 3-dimensional vectors v and w, and produces a 3-dimensional vector vxw perpendicular to both, whose length is the area of the parallelogram whose sides are v and w, hence which is nonzero when v and w are not parallel. Implement the cross product yourself, or find it in a vector library, or look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566072/cross-product-of-vectors-in-c).

Given n, choose a vector v that is not parallel. nxv is perpendicular to n. Normalize this to get a unit vector u1 perpendicular to n. nxu1 is perpendicular to both n and u1. Normalize this to get u2. The points p+-u1, p+-u2 form a square with side length sqrt(2) whose center is p.

It is natural to want to have a way to choose the points continuously. This is impossible even if you restrict to unit vectors n by the [Hairy Ball Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). You have to allow a discontinuous choice of v. For example, you could use v = (1,0,0) unless n is a nonzero multiple of (1,0,0), and then use v = (0,1,0) there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to get you started:

Every vector on the plane is orthogonal to the normal to the plane. I.e., for an arbitrary point x on the plane, `(x - p)` is a vector parallel to the plane and its dot product with the given normal `n` is zero:

```
n*(x - p) = 0
```

This should give you the equation of the plane and allow you to find as many points on the plane as you need.

Edit: An example:

```
n = (n1,n2,n3) ;  p = (p1,p2,p3); x = (x1,x2,x3)

n1*(x1-p1) + n2*(x2-p2) + n3*(x3-p3) = 0
```

Now set for example, `x1=0; x2=0` and extract `x3` from the equation. Similarly, it is possible to set `x1=0; x3=0` and determine `x2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A way to find vectors orthogonal to your original vector that does not even involve transformations is simply reordering the coordinates. For any vector (x,y,z), one orthogonal would be (y,z,x), and then (z,x,y) would be orthogonal to both.

Comment: Are you sure about that ?
What about verctor (1,1,1). If you reorder coordinates as you said you will get the same vector, but as far as I know no vector is othogonal to it self.

Comment: @LovelyHanibal You have a point. Values exist for which this method does not work. However, it is still an attractive solution because of the extremely low computational overhead.

Comment: Your method works only for scaled vertices (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1).
If 0<x and 0<y and 0<z then every vertex ortogonal to (x,y,z) will have 1 or 2 coordiances below 0, but you are giving all positive values. Same story if x,y,z < 0.